# What arguments are passed to entry point of a PE (Portable Executable) file?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, portable-executable

If you assemble a PE (.exe, portable executable for Win32) file it has an entry point which you could call `_start`, `_main` or whatever you like.

The question is - is this entry point called with some args? If so, are they accessible in the stack? If so, does this entry point function need to clear the stack? Where can I find some documentation about this?

Comment: The value of the FS register, in a sense...

Comment: The technical term for what you're asking about is the ABI (application binary interface) for windows processes.  The ABI also tells you what you can expect about the state of registers and so on in a newly-execed process.  (e.g. the Unix x86-64 ABI says most of them are uninitialized.  In practice Linux zeroes them, to not leak kernel data.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the process does not have any information about it's arguments on the stack at the entry point. You have to call `GetCommandLine` or access the information in the PEB via [RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813741.aspx), but that's not a stable API.

Every language support library (like the CRT) has to do this as well.

Comment: could you maybe said where to find info on this? On windows process structure internals in mSDN? sorta like that?

Comment: @user2214913 Info on what exactly? The documentation of the PEB is liked as related on the struct I linked. You could also check out the source code of the CRT.

Comment: Well i dont now, documentation on calling conditions of this special 'function' /entry point.. do you know maybe if just simply ret in this function is proper way of exit? (as im not sure)

Comment: @user2214913 I don't think microsoft has documented this stuff anywhere. Looking at the code you can safely return from the entry point. It will return to BaseThreadInitThunk in kernel32.dll which then instantly exits the process.

Comment: could you maybe say yet how you see this? in debugger? what is that code.. if kernell32.dll is a parent of this process i think kernel32.dll is closed source, how can you see what id dona above the entry call in your process?

Comment: @user2214913 I used a debugger "OllyDbg" that works well when source code is not available, because of good assembly analysis. Similar software: x64dbg, IDA.

Comment: @user2214913: The raw entry point signature is `DWORD CALLBACK RawEntryPoint(void)`. I believe I saw that documented in the MSDN, but couldn't find it anymore. You can find reliable information at [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/25/10168020.aspx), though.

Comment: Interesting.  It's apparently a *lot* different from the [Linux x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), where your command line arguments and env vars are pointed to by arguments on the stack on entry to `_start`.  It's amusing that cmdline args are second-class citizens even at the ABI level.  You have to ask the OS to give them to you, rather than having them there by default.  Also in Linux, you can't return from `_start`.  (you use the `exit()` system call).  The dynamic library ABI is separate from the kernel process exec ABI, so there's no kernel32.dll equivalent.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You are wrong, pretty much with everything you said. The command line arguments are passed to a newly created process through the [PEB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx). A process doesn't need to query the OS. While you can return from a native Windows executable's entry point, this doesn't terminate the process. You have to call [ExitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx) on Windows as well. *kernel32.dll* is not a kernel module. I'm puzzled as to what point you were trying to make.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for the correction on cmdline args being in a new process's address space after all.  The answer we're commenting on says that "isn't a stable API", though.  So what happens if you return from the entry point?  Does the code you return to just make a sleep-forever system call or something, instead of exiting or infinite-looping?  In Linux, there isn't a valid return address on the stack, so you just segfault if you try to return.

Comment: The point I was trying to make about kernel32.dll is that in Linux, the only binary that's mapped into the virtual memory of a new process is that binary's own text/data/bss segments.  You can make a static executable that never maps any shared libraries at all.  (Normal dynamically-linked binaries don't actually run directly, though: an exec on a dynamic binary actually runs `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on it (or whatever ELF interpreter it specifies), just like running a shell script actually invokes `/bin/sh` on the script.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33970159/224132 for example).

Comment: @PeterCordes: in fact, the vdso and vsyscall are mapped into all processes, even static executables.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: interesting point.  Yeah, Linux could have been designed to put the vdso address of an exit function on the stack.  But only for x86-64, because the 32-bit ABI was stable before vdso existed, right?  So a change to the process startup environment would have broken existing static binaries (including /lib/ld.so).  In reality, those pages don't provide any new functionality you can't get from running `syscall` or `int 0x80` instructions directly, right?  (unlike kernel32.dll) They're just for avoiding user->kernel->user switches for stuff like `gettimeofday()` and `getpid()`.