# `bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory` on running executable produced by `ld`

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

Here is a Hello World code in C:

```
// a.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as `gcc a.c`, which produces `a.out` as expected and `./a.out` prints `Hello world`... as expected.

Now if I do the compile and link separately: 
`gcc -c a.c; ld -lc a.o`, it run the `a.out` produced as `./a.out` I get the message:

```
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

I Googled that error and it seems that happens when the executable produced is a 32-bit ELF and the machine architecture is 64-bit.

I'm running a 64-bit machine and running `file a.out` gives:

```
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT:

Output of `uname -m`

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Output of `ldd a.out`

```
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeeedfb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa13a7b8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa13abab000)
```

`gcc a.c` produces `a.out` which runs correctly.

Comment: A 64-bit machine doesn't necessarily mean a 64-bit OS. What's the output of `uname -m`?

Comment: What does `ldd a.out` produce?  What happens when you do `gcc a.c`?

Comment: Added the outputs as edits to the question

Comment: Have you tried running the problematic `a.out` under gdb?

Comment: @MichaelBurr same error, `/bin/bash: /home/pratyaksh/temp/a.out: No such file or directory
`

Comment: you can execute: gcc -v a.c and check the link stage (do you need to link with the startup object usually crt0.o)

Comment: @arrowd Tried that, doesn't change things :-)

Comment: Why don't you want to let gcc handle the linking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Link dynamic executables with `gcc foo.o` (to use the right paths for CRT and libc, and the dynamic linker / ELF interpreter `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`).
Or `gcc -nostartfiles foo.o` for libc but not CRT `_start`, if you have a hand-written `_start`

(For static executables without libc or CRT, you can use `ld` directly or `gcc -nostdlib -static`.)

`gcc -v foo.o` will show you the actual paths GCC used on your system.

---

The other answers only address how to avoid this<sup>1</sup>, not the **actual question of what happened**.

The `gcc -c a.c; ld -lc a.o` commands you gave produce a pretty obvious warning:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400260
```

So even if this file could be executed, it will probably crash right away.  **See @EmployedRussian's answer** for an explanation of what you should have done.

---

#### The question of why it can't even be executed is still interesting:

```
$ strace ./a.out 
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 72 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

`execve(2)` returns ENOENT because it can't find the interpreter (which I figured out from `file` and so on, see below).  You'd get the same error from trying to run a file that started with

```
#!/usr/non-existant-path/bin/bash
```

As you discovered, the usual reason for this error message is when running an ELF binary on a system without the right dynamic linker and dynamic libraries installed (e.g. a 64bit system without 32bit support installed).  In your case, it's because you used a bad link command and made a dynamic executable with a bad interpreter path.

---

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, where GNU `file` version 5.22 reports:

```
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, not stripped
```

There is no `/lib/ld64.so.1` on my system.  `ldd` output is confusing, because `ldd` uses its default ELF interpreter, not the one specified by the binary.

```
$ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc18d2b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0e0a79f000)
        /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559dbc9d2000)
```

So it assumes that the runtime interpreter in the binary resolved to the one `ldd` used itself, I guess.

Your `ldd` output is probably from an old version too, since it just shows `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for that line.  Not taking a bad guess is probably better behaviour, for a weird case like this, but doesn't help you see that your binary has a weird interpreter path.

```
readelf -l a.out
```

will decode the ELF headers for you, including the interpreter path.  (Thanks to @EmployedRussian's comment for pointing this out.)

Comment: The standard way to see what the interpreter is for a given binary is `readelf -l a.out | grep interpreter`

Answer (score 11):

> `ld -lc a.o`

There are several things wrong with this command line:

1. In general, user-level code should *never* use `ld` directly, and *always* use appropriate compiler front end (`gcc` here) to perform the link.

   As you have discovered, the link command line that `gcc` constructs is quite complicated, and the command line that you've accepted in Joan Esteban's answer is wrong.

   If you want to see the *actual* link command, examine output from `gcc -v a.o`.

   Also note that link command changes significantly when you change `gcc` command only slightly (e.g. some OSes require different `crt1.o` depending on whether you are linking multi-threaded executable or not), and the command line is always OS-specific (which is one more reason to *never* use `ld` directly).
2. Libraries should follow object files on command line. So `ld -lc a.o` is *never* correct, and should *always* be (a variant of) `ld a.o -lc`. [Explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Comment: explanation archived link https://web.archive.org/web/20180627210132/http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html

Answer (score 5):

Use that:

```
  ld -o a.out -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o -lc c.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

Comment: First, `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` are present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` on my machine. After changing that and running `ld` and then the `a.out`, I get the error: `bash: ./a.out: Accessing a corrupted shared library`

Comment: @pratyaksh You also need to adapt the linker to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` .

Comment: @piggs_boson: That's a good reason to link dynamic executables with `gcc c.o` or `gcc -nostartfiles c.o` instead of `ld` manually - your distro will have configured it to use the right paths *for your system*.  Use `gcc -v` to see what those paths are on your system, rather than someone else's on the Internet.