# Building my assembly program on native RISC-V

Tags: assembly, compilation, linker, riscv, crt

I have been working on a project in RISC-V assembly for a while in expectation of the imminent arrival of single board RISC-V devices (https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/riscyforth).

I have been using Spike with pk proxy kernel (ie I have Linux-like system calls available). Using a cross-compiler I can build it very simply:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc riscyforth.S -o riscyforth
```

That will then run via Spike and pk:

```
spike ./path-to-pk/pk riscyforth
```

But now, I actually have an SBC that runs on RISC-V and boots to Linux.

I can get what looks like an executable by:

```
as riscyforth.S -o something

ld something -lc -o riscyforth
```

But while that generates something with a symbol table that looks like a real thing, it doesn't run (reporting that "riscyforth cannot be found").

I am guessing I need to also link a crt0 or something similar? Is that right? My code has a `main` entry point but on compiling the compiler reports it cannot find `_start` (which also happens if I make `main` and `_start` point to the same thing) and uses a default value instead.

If I need the crt, is there a standard format or a ready made one I can convert?

The good thing is is that my code reports no other errors on compilation (but why would it if it cross-compiles?), so I am hopeful I can get this to work.

Comment: When `./foo` fails with "file not found", that can be from the ELF interpreter (dynamic linker) being an invalid path, even when the executable is there.  (`readelf -a foo` and look for the interpreter path, or use `file foo`)  Try using `gcc -nostartfiles riscyforth.S` to still link libc, and specify the correct default path to the dynamic linker.

Comment: This worked. If you’d like to write it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: I updated my existing answer ([\`bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory\` on running executable produced by \`ld\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33970159)) with a better TL:DR recipe at the top so it works as a duplicate for this, containing an explanation of what's going on as well as the fix.