# GDB: File not found/required file not found

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I'm aware this topic has been asked, but I have followed the steps of each, and none seem to work.

I am currently attempting to understand the functionality of an executable in which I was not given source code for. This means I had no control over the compilation of it, etc. It is a ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64 file.

To do so, I thought back to my computer architecture course, where we learned how to step through a program using gdb. I am currently attempting to use this, but I am running into a strange error, something along the lines of this when I attempt to run within the gdb debugger:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: /home/ec2-user/filename: cannot execute: required file not found
```

I say "something along the lines of" because I have tried this in both an Ubuntu22 instance as well as an Amazon Linux instance. Both return their same flavors of the error above. I sanity tested with

```
gdb thisfiledoesnotexist
```

And gdb explicitly told me that the file did not exist immediately upon entering the debugger, whereas with filename, it only stated it when I attempted to run. I could set breakpoints and do what limited things you can do without a frame or a running program.

A few things to note:

1. I have the file at ~/
2. I ran gdb in the ~/ directory
3. I ran `dir /home/ec2-user` within the debugger
4. I did a "normal" install, so just sudo yum/apt install

I tested on a bash-native date file, which did indeed work, so it's not that gdb is the issue.

This leads me to believe one of a few things:

1. This executable doesn't play well with gdb, but it also didn't work with lldb
2. I'm failing to configure gdb correctly.
3. I am missing something in bin/bash to allow this executable to run

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of the shell command `file  /home/ec2-user/filename`

Comment: Silly question, but are you on an arm machine? Otherwise you will need qemu.

Comment: MarkPlotnick, it's `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, BuildID[sha1]=b669ddfe2f9bb804fec87e1bc3a8254ed993a64e, stripped`. That's how I figured out the type of file

Comment: Jester Yes, it's an ARM EC2 instance.

Comment: For dynamically-linked executables using `ld` manually, see [\`bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory\` on running executable produced by \`ld\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33970159) - the default ELF-interpreter path is not appropriate for some systems.

Comment: How were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I didn't. I swapped to Ghidra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64,`

The problem (most likely) is that `/system/bin/linker64` does not exist on your system.

This is possibly an Android binary (using Bionic `libc`), and you are trying to run it on a "regular" Linux.

Searching for ["run android app on linux"](https://www.google.com/search?q=run%20android%20app%20on%20linux) provides many possible answers, though I am not sure which one is most appropriate here.